# Msbuild file with grunt giving error while executing from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

I am executing my Msbuild file from Jenkins using below command using Execute windows batch command option.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild "D:****\Build Scripts\BuildAndDeploy.proj"

this command executing perfectly from command prompt but in jenkins I am getting below error...

'grunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
D:****\Build Scripts\BuildAndDeploy.proj(29,3): error MSB3073: The command "grunt build" exited with code 9009.
Done Building Project "D:*****\Build Scripts\BuildAndDeploy.proj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

Please suggest me how to handle this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're calling `grunt` without specifying a ful path to the executable, and the executable's directory is also not in your system's `PATH` environment variable. Fix one of those 2.

Comment: Actually I am using custom working directory in Jenkins and when I run grunt statement from command prompt in that directory it will rung. I could able to figure out the issue. The user I am using to run jenkins doesn't have full rights on the directory I am using as workspace. Once I changed the user it is working perfectly.

Comment: Ah, a third option, nice :] Either post it as an answer to your own question so it's usable for future visitors, or else delete your question else it just remains unanswered forever.